# How do I disable a field that's a global picklist from recordtypes where it's not required?

Tags: record-type, global-picklist

In my Account object I have 3 record types - customers, suppliers and other. For suppliers I need some fields that are not required for customers, and some of these fields are global picklists as they use the same values. A global picklist does not allow you not to set a value, so how do I do this?

Comment: Tt sounds like you're interested in required field(s) per page layout & record type rather than on the object definition itself. Have you looked into this yet?

Comment: Create a page layout for record type Supplier and remove the picklist field. Then you don't care about the global value set

Comment: It turned out to be one of the picklists using the global one I hadn't set for the recordtype (there are 5 of them using the same global one) :) I do have a page layout for each record type, but it wasn't that.